# How to save a file on macos desktop using kml in python?

Tags: python, macos, if-statement, kml, simplekml

I have just read some of posts on how to save a kml file on macos desktop in Python but i couldn't find the answer.I try to locate the file path but it doesn't work.
my code is:

```
import pathlib
import simplekml

longitude = input("Enter longitude: ")
latitude = input("Enter longitude: ")

kml = simplekml.Kml()
kml.newpoint(name="Sample", coords=[(longitude, latitude)])
kml.save("~/Desktop/bura/Points.kml")
```

The problem starts with `kml.save("~/Desktop/bura/Points.kml")` it doesn't find the path and doesn't save the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kml` probably does not expand `~`, but you can do it explicitly:

```
import os
...
kml.save(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/bura/Points.kml"))
```